# can flutter invokes my own sdk

Tags: dart, flutter

I am newer to flutter, and evaluates whether we can use in our project. In our project, we need to use some existing sdk which is built by java. I didn't find any document to introduce how can call existing java api.

Comment: https://flutter.io/platform-channels/ - for native interop, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Will probably only work on Android.

Comment: thanks, I didn't go through all document